# mongoose.js: on building great schema's | nested vs reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to get my head around the concepts of a great schema design for my database structure. Should i embed nested documents or should i use a reference?

I have this structure:

```
book
 | bookTitle
 | bookChapters
 | | chapterTitle
 | | chapterArticles
 | | | articleTitle
 | | | articleSubTitles
 | | | | title
```

I will be having multiple books with their chapters and articles. So i have 2 questions:

1. how would my mongoose schema look like (1 schema vs multiple
   schema's / embed vs reference)
2. How would i query for instance all chapterTitles from bookTitle x

Thx for you help, i guess i'm almost ready to go on my own when i understand these fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the schema in your database, then you could use a mongoose schema like this:

```
var articleSubTitleSchema = new Schema({title: 'string'});
var articleSchema = new Schema({title: 'string', articleSubTitles: [articleSubTitleSchema]});
var chapterSchema = new Schema({title: 'string', chapterArticles: [articleSchema]});
var bookSchema = new Schema({title: 'string', 'bookChapters': [chapterSchema]});
```

Your best bet for part two is to simple fetch the entire book document, and get the chapters in application code.

```
var book = ... query ...
var chapters = book.bookChapters;
var chapterTitles = _.pluck(chapters, 'title');
```

Here I use http://underscorejs.org/ to make grabbing the titles a little easier.

If you wanted to search for all books with a particular chapter, you could write a query like: `{'bookChapters.titles': '[title]'}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no developer who does not favor splitting up single documents in mongodb :) Unfortunately this is only nice in theoretical thoughts. Practically there is no support for this neither from mongodb nor from mongoose.

Sure there are support of references but believe me every approach in this direction is punished by a lot of time just invested for the result that there are too much negative side effects (population, extra saving, ...) then benefits in comparison if we save stuff extra.

This is my experience so far. Except you want to write an own layer on top of mongodb-native you will have a lot of pain trying to work with references.